# How can I improve on reducing a "scanline" noise in an image?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have an image with scanline noises. The noise is probably simulated with some sinusoid functions. I want to remove the noise, and so what I did was to transform the image with `fft2`, pick out the coordinates of the peaks in the spectrum. The peaks turn out to have a conjugate pair.

So, I took their coordinates (the conjugate pair), set its surrounding pixels to zero in the frequency domain, and the did a `ifft2` to get back the image. I was pretty much trying to do a band rejection on the frequency of the peaks. The scanline noise is reduced by a lot with this method.

But I thought, how else can I improve on this method to get better results?

Comment: an example image with and without your noise reduction would be a great addition to your post.

Comment: Well, clearly fft2 is the best approach since scanline noise is periodic. The only way I see you could improve your method is by selecting a small box around the peaks, but I guess you may already be doing that.

Comment: @CTZStef Yes, they are periodic, and I did the same thing as you said by selecting a small box around the peaks. But I was thinking if there are other small improvements that I could do to improve on this technique.

Comment: Maybe a circle instead of a box ? Seems to me to be more correct in term of distance to the peak center.